# Facebook User has not installed the application (code 412)

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Today between 14:00 - 17:00 (UTC+0) %50 of the calls to the method GET me/permissions resulted in errors.

"User has not installed the application (code 412, subcode null)"

Facebook API version : 2.8

Why this error occur ?

Any answer will be appreciated.

Comment: Ever make any progress on this Ersin?

Comment: I did not find any solution. Only I know that "This problem occur on Facebook Servers then fixed"